# Polymorphic association without sharing primary key in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have to support third-party DB with the following schema (looks like RoR style?).

[image: DB diagram]

Here is master table **Vehicle** where *VehicleType* is a discriminator (possible values are `'Car'` and `'Bike'`). So in case *VehicleType* = `'Car'` then *SubId* points to record in **Car** table, if *VehicleType* = `'Bike'` then records points to **Bike** table.

And plus tables don't share primary keys values.

I want to avoid complex logic in my code, but I can't understand if I can use inheritance here (so `Car : Vehicle` and `Bike : Vehicle`) or at least navigation property (so `Car.Vehicle` and `Bike.Vehicle` could work). So the question is can I use something of this? How to implement this?

Comment: If you can't change DB schema, all what you can is just create 3 independent classes without any inheritance strategy and navigation properties as `Car.Vehicle`, because they are only possible in case of FKs.

Comment: Thanks @SlavaUtesinov, it seems you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tables don't share primary keys values

So there's no way to map this to one inheritance schema, which should have been [TPT](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt). The different primary key values prevent this.

What's left is mapping different classes that are connected to each other, so you can at least use navigation properties instead of manually joining unrelated entities. I found a way to do this, but it's not ideal. Actually, it's pretty contrived. But just see if it's a viable solution for you.

I used these classes:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public VehicleInfo VehicleInfo { get; set; }
}
public class CarVehicle : Vehicle
{ }
public class BikeVehicle : Vehicle
{ }

public abstract class VehicleInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class CarInfo : VehicleInfo
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
public class BikeInfo : VehicleInfo
{
    public bool IsEbike { get; set; }
}
```

I split up table `Vehicle` into the entities `CarVehicle` and `BikeVehicle` by [TPH](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().ToTable("Vehicle");
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
    .Map<CarVehicle>(m => m.Requires("VehicleType").HasValue("Car"))
    .Map<BikeVehicle>(m => m.Requires("VehicleType").HasValue("Bike")
        .HasColumnType("CHAR")
        .HasMaxLength(4));
```

`CarInfo` and `BikeInfo`, on the other hand, must have their own tables, so here I used [TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleInfo>()
    .Map<CarInfo>(c =>
    {
        c.MapInheritedProperties().ToTable("Car");
        c.Property(x => x.ID).HasColumnName("CarId");
        c.Property(x => x.Model);
    })
    .Map<BikeInfo>(c =>
    {
        c.MapInheritedProperties().ToTable("Bike");
        c.Property(x => x.ID).HasColumnName("BikeId");
        c.Property(x => x.IsEbike);
    });
```

And finally, connecting the classes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasRequired(c => c.VehicleInfo)
    .WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("SubId"));
```

By using the base type `VehicleInfo` it's possible to map one property `Vehicle.VehicleInfo` through the one foreign key `SubId`. It is not possible to have this:

```
public class CarVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public CarInfo CarInfo { get; set; }
}
public class BikeVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public BikeInfo BikeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

EF won't accept it if you try to map both navigation properties through `SubId`.

The main drawback of this model is that you'll always have to get the "Info" entities as `VehicleInfo` objects. EF will create the correct subtypes, but their compile-time type is `VehicleInfo`. Likewise, if you set the `VehicleInfo` property, you have to remember to provide the correct type. You can somewhat mitigate that by a pass-through property ...

```
public class CarVehicle : Vehicle
{
    [NotMapped]
    public CarInfo CarInfo
    {
        get { return VehicleInfo as CarInfo; }
        set { VehicleInfo = value; }
    }
}
```

... and the same in `BikeVehicle`. But you won't be able to use this property in a LINQ query directly, because it isn't (and can't be) mapped.

Further, the executed SQL from something simple as ...

```
db.Set<CarVehicle>().Include(c => c.VehicleInfo).ToList();
```

... is humongous because of EF digging through all inheritance trees.

Comment: You. Are. Genuis! This helps a lot :)